# preg_replace pattern replacement versus single character?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am using this line to replace a silly string with this `^_^` pattern

```
$newText = trim(preg_replace('/\^_^+/', "\r\n", $newText));
```

The patterns can be like this or multiples of the same ...

```
^_^ OR ^_^^_^ or ^_^^_^^_^
```

I am not exactly the king of regular expressions,, can someone help me understand how to replace a string versus a single character?

It works when I want to replace a single string or multiples of the same like this `^` for example..

```
$newText = trim(preg_replace('/\^+/', "\r\n", $newText));
```

I tried this and other similar combinations with no luck

```
preg_replace('/\^_\^+/', "\r\n", $newText)
```

Comment: Match: `^`, then `_`, and then 1 or more `^` (<- This is what you do right now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape both `^`s and wrap `\^_\^` in parentheses:

```
$newText = trim(preg_replace('/(\^_\^)+/', "\r\n", $newText));
```

Comment: So parentheses denotes a pattern and ^ is a special character?

Comment: @GRowing the parentheses indicate a group or pattern and are necessary if you want to detect repetitions of anything longer than a single character or character class. `^` is a special character meaning the beginning of the subject string.